# Is there a `std::` equivalent to libdispatch's `dispatch_data_t`?

Tags: c++, c++11, grand-central-dispatch

I'm fond of `dispatch_data_t`. It provides a useful abstraction on top of a range of memory: it provides reference counting, allows consumers to create arbitrary sub-ranges (which participate in the ref counting of the parent range), concatenate sub-ranges, etc. (I won't bother to get into the gory details -- the docs are right over here: [Managing Dispatch Data Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW77))

I've been trying to find out if there's a C++11 equivalent, but the terms "range", "memory" and "reference counting" are pretty generic, which is making googling for this a bit of a challenge. I suspect that someone who spends more time with the C++ Standard Library than I do might know off the top of their head.

Yes, I'm aware that I can use the `dispatch_data_t` API from C++ code, and yes, I'm aware that it would not be difficult to crank out a naive first pass implementation of such a thing, but I'm specifically looking for something idiomatic to C++, and with a high degree of polish/reliability. (Boost maybe?)

Comment: I do not believe that the standard library has anything quite like that.  You'll likely have to resort to a third party library.

Comment: What parts of dispatch_data_t are you using? If your needs are simple enough, you could base your class on a class simply containing a std::vector used through a std::shared_ptr, perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Range views are being proposed for future standard revisions, but they are non-owning.

`dispatch_data_t` is highly tied to GCD in that cleanup occurs in a specified queue determined at creation: to duplicate that behaviour, we would need thread pools and queues in `std`, which we do not have.

As you have noted, an owning overlapping immutable range type into sparse or contiguous memory would not be hard to write up.  Fully poished it would have to support allocators, some kind of raw input buffer system (type erasure on the owning/destruction mechanism?), have utlities for asynchronous iteration by block (with tuned block size), deal with errors and exceptions carefully, and some way to efficiently turn rc 1 views into mutable versions.

Something that complex would first have to show up in a library like `boost` and go through iterative improvements.  And as it is quite many faceted, something with enough of its properties for your purposes may already be there.

If you roll your own I encourage you to submit it for `boost` consideration.

Comment: Suppose for a minute that I don't care about the 'destruction on a specific queue'? Does removing that requirement yield something usable?

Comment: @ipmcc not to my knowledge: there are so many details and quirks in that type (immutability, non-contiguous range appending, merging rules not exactly clear from interface, reallocation into contiguous, block-level iteration with logical offset) that I dount anything matches it perfectly.  Definitely not in `std`: check `boost`.